# How can I make these 4 images equidistant horizontally in a div with .css?

Tags: html, css

Thats it really.

each image is a button, and I want them to all fit in the container equidistant

```
<div class="buttonImgContainer" >
      <span><img class="buttonImg servicesImg" src="Images/services.jpg" alt="" /></span>
      <span><img class="buttonImg galleryImg" src="Images/ProjectGallery.jpg" alt="" /></span>
      <span><img class="buttonImg estimateImg" src="Images/Estimate.jpg" alt=""/></span>
      <span><img class="buttonImg contactImg" src="Images/ContactUsSquare.png" alt=""/></span>
</div>
```

Comment: are the images the same width and height?

Comment: as in: | i  i  i  i | or |i  i  i  i  | ?

Comment: @Andres, does it matter?

Comment: Yes, it does matter. If they have different sizes, my method will resize them and other methods might not work. If they have the same size, adjust the percentages until you are happy, but making the sum of them 100%. PS, margin counts double since it is in both sides.

Comment: @KevinDeus there are multiple approaches to go about it, if all of your images had the same width we can come up with a much much easier solution to your question.

Comment: yes they are all the same width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that I was quite close with my prior answer.  This unequivocally does it:

```
.buttonImgContainer span {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

span{
    text-align: center;
}
```

here's a [.jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KevinGabbert/4EaPr/2/) for the solve.

In my case, I am using `<span>`s, which are inline.  `text-align: center;` is badly named, as it will align images as well. That was the missing piece of the puzzle.. The name threw me off.

Each span is set to 25% of its parent `<div>`, which, in turn, I have made smaller than the page, showing the spans are keyed to that element.

in my fiddle, if you resize the columns, you will see the buttons move to their proper place in relation to the containing div, `.buttonImgContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited and tested it here: [Link](http://newfutureuniversity.org/test/stack2.php)

You probably want the radio to be kept, but I wasn't sure about what size you wanted so I let you choose. Here is the code I changed:

```
<div>
<span><img style="width:21%; left: 2%; top: 200px; position: absolute;" class="buttonImg servicesButtonImg" src="http://ec2-50-17-14-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Sites/EvergreenPlumbing/Images/services.jpg" alt="" /></span>
<span><img style="width:21%; left: 27%; top: 200px; position: absolute;" class="buttonImg projectGalleryButtonImg" src="http://ec2-50-17-14-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Sites/EvergreenPlumbing/Images/ProjectGallery.jpg" alt="" /></span>
<span><img style="width:21%; left: 52%; top: 200px; position: absolute;" class="buttonImg estimateButtonImg" src="http://ec2-50-17-14-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Sites/EvergreenPlumbing/Images/Estimate.jpg" alt=""/></span>
<span><img style="width:21%; left: 77%; top: 200px; position: absolute;" class="buttonImg contactUsButtonImg" src="http://ec2-50-17-14-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Sites/EvergreenPlumbing/Images/ContactUsSquare.png" alt=""/></span>
</div>
```

Which could be resumed as

```
.buttonImgContainer img
{
width:21%;
left: 2%;
top: 200px;
position: absolute;
}
```

This works fine. NOTE: you MUST delete the tag class="buttonImgContainer" if you do inline css, else internet explorer (don't know why) won't work at all. It doesn't work 100% as expected, but it does decently.

Comment: Changed, see if it works as you wanted now. Ofc, resize the icons as you like, the only thing is that the width must be in %.

Comment: is there a way to do this without absolute values?

Comment: your method doesn't appear to resize the images in respect to their enclosing div (making your enclosing div 50% smaller has no effect).  it seems the images are hardcoded to the size of the page

Comment: Yes, it is hardcoded to the size of the page (position:absolute). The problem is that the div starts almost at the middle of the page, so the other solution would be to center the div (somehow) and to give it a different width. But then it depends on each display to show them equidistantly from the sides or not. Apart you'd need to deal with negative margins to center the content with your scheme.

Comment: I totally appreciate you looking at this. I have a number of ways that I could solve the issues with the content of my scheme, but I have determined that part of it is an inability to center items within a div.  when I remove all elements but the 4 images I still run into this problem. That's the question that I'm looking to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Writing

```
.buttonImgContainer img {
 width: 40px; /* Can be anything - also percentages. */
}
```

should work. 
`.buttonImgContainer` matches the class of the outer div and `img` makes sure this is only applied to images inside the `.buttonImgContainer`.

Edit: Or wait.. By equidistant do you mean separated by equal distance? In that case the code would be something like:

```
.buttonImgContainer { 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.buttonImgContainer img {
 margin-right: 40px; /* Can be anything - also percentages. */
}
```

Sorry if I misunderstood :-)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me:

```
.buttonImgContainer span {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}


#buttonImgContainer img {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the right button go too much to the right side with this? Also, it should be .buttonImgContainer img instead of #buttonImgContainer img, as it is a [class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)

Comment: actually, it works in Chrome and FF but not in IE.  My answer appears not to be a good one.

Comment: What happens with IE? Could you provide a link so we can see? You are defining both statements as class and id, so weirdly enough IE could do it just right and Chrome and FF be more flexible and accept it. Or maybe they work because they don't accept the second statement or...there are many options. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: i did. I think I also edited my answer after you saw it.  whatever the case.. (I've been playing with it since I posted, but you will see its not right)  http://ec2-50-17-14-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Sites/EvergreenPlumbing/home.html

Answer (score 0):

i write this example you can check it.

first you can define span tag properties in css display:table-cell

as like this

**css**

```
span{
    display:table-cell;
    padding-left:10px;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttonImgContainer" >
      <span><img class="buttonImg servicesImg" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/a334a3/fff.jpg" alt="" /></span>
      <span><img class="buttonImg galleryImg" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/a334a3/fff.jpg" alt="" /></span>
      <span><img class="buttonImg estimateImg" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/a334a3/fff.jpg" alt=""/></span>
      <span><img class="buttonImg contactImg" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/a334a3/fff.jpg" alt=""/></span>
</div>​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/LeY6t/2/